# What is the difference between Culture and UICulture?

Tags: .net, culture, uiculture

Could someone give me a bit more information on the difference between `Culture` and `UICulture` within the .NET framework? What they do and when to use what?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

`Culture` affects how culture-dependent data (dates, currencies, numbers and so on) is presented. Here are a few examples:

```
var date = new DateTime(2000, 1, 2);
var number = 12345.6789;

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
Console.WriteLine(date); // 02.01.2000 00:00:00
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("C")); // 12.345,68 €

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-CA");
Console.WriteLine(date); // 2000-01-02 00:00:00
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("C")); // 12 345,68 $

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Console.WriteLine(date); // 1/2/2000 12:00:00 AM
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("C")); // $12,345.68
```

Culture also affects parsing of user input in the same way:

```
const string numberString = "12.345,68";
decimal money;

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
money = decimal.Parse(numberString); // OK!

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
money = decimal.Parse(numberString); // FormatException is thrown, TryParse would return false
```

Beware of cases where the parsing *succeeds* but the result is not what you would expect it to be.

```
const string numberString = "12.345";
decimal money;

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
money = decimal.Parse(numberString); // 12345

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
money = decimal.Parse(numberString); // 12.345, where the . is a decimal point
```

`UICulture` affects which resource file (Resources.*lang*.resx) is going to be loaded to by your application.

So to load German resources (presumably localized text) you would set `UICulture` to the German culture and to display German formatting (without any impact on which resources are loaded) you would set `Culture`.

Comment: Which means you can have english labels and UI (english UICulture), and norwegian currency, date, time, and number formatting (norwegian Culture.) In Windows-terms, think of it as having a language pack installed for the menus and dialog boxes (UICulture), but running with norwegian regional settings (Culture.)

Comment: To emphasize the implications of this:  Even if you don't support a user's language, make sure you support their culture, for formatting!  I've seen mistakes where an app falls back to "en-US" both for culture and language, when it only needed to fallback for language.

Comment: What is the point in using an entire `CultureInfo` object just to determine the resource file where a `string` would be sufficient? (E.g. the `Language` property of the `FrameworkElement`)

Answer (score 4):

`Culture and UICulture`

Values are pairs of two-letter strings, the first is for defining language and the second for defining the region.
Example:

`en-GB` here `en` represents `English` and `GB` represents `Great Briton`

`en-US` here `en` represents `English` and `US` represents `United States`

Use `Culture` for Culture dependent functions like date, time.
and `UICulture` is for correct resource file loading.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small matter to consider in addition to @Vache's awesome explanation:
You can set both UICulture and Culture at (page level and application level).

In order to set them at application level, simply add globalization session in web.config

e.g. `<globalization uiCulture="es" culture="es-MX" />`

And to set them at the page level, which is good to add on a specific (individual) page, set the Culture and UICulture attributes within @ page directive

e.g. `<%@ Page UICulture="es" Culture="es-MX" %>`

Answer (score -5):

The UICulture property might change for each Web browser, whereas the Culture stays constant.

The Culture value can be set to specific cultures only, such as en-US or en-GB. This prevents the requirement to identify the correct currency symbol to use for en, where en-US and en-GB have different currency symbols.
Users can set the UI culture and culture in their browsers.