# Invalid characters in date crystal reports

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, crystal-reports

I have formatted date field in crystal reports to show full day name and full month name. Like this

[image: Format Object]

It works locally but not on my production server. This is how it looks on pdf generated on server.

[image]

My website is using asp.net. I recently switched production server and my new server is doing this, old one just works fine.

Comment: What's the actual problem? I can't see anything wrong with the output. Do you not like the use of Spanish day names and month names? Change the culture of the application, then

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060184/how-to-set-culture-as-globally-in-mvc5 on how to change the culture of an asp.mvc app.

Comment: It fixed the issue, but I wonder why everything else is English but just this crystal report date is Spanish. Is there any setting in IIS too?

Comment: Got it. IIS had .Net Globalization setting which was invariant language (invariant country). This was causing an issue.