# Excel Object Model, will Value2 be culture specific?

Tags: c#, excel, range, culture

on My PC I have English version (US) Excel 2013 
I changed region to Germany, set value "550,66231278" to a cell in Excel
When I read cell.Value2, I see in Visual Studio it is "550.66231278"

So I wonder if Value2 is always in US culture format or it is culture specific 
say, if I install Germany version of Excel, Value2 will be "550,66231278"?

Thanks

Comment: "I see in Visual Studio" - you mean in some app created with VS or in the debugger itself. Because the debugger usually uses neutral  culture for floating point values like '1.123' .

Comment: And if it is in some app, then are you sure that it(app) uses German Culture and UICulture?

Comment: @Eugene, Yes, I created an app in VS and debug it in VS. So you mean this is b/c VS uses neutral culture?   My visual studio is English (US) version.

Comment: I am not sure, but try to output this value in the app into some textBox or label.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value2.aspx) says:

> The only difference between this property and the Value property is
>   that the Value2 property doesn’t use the Currency and Date data types.
>   You can return values formatted with these data types as
>   floating-point numbers by using the Double data type.

So the most probable is that your value is displayed in CultureNeutral fashion during the debugging or usage in the app. Try to [change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454024/setting-culture-en-in-globally-in-wpf-app) the [culture and possibly UICulture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507582/what-is-the-difference-between-culture-and-uiculture) in your app.