# MVC globalization with different DLLs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, globalization

I have designed my MVC application in the following way:

```
-Portal.UI ( hold all the Views and controllers details)
    - App_GlobalResources
        - Global.en-GB.resx
        - Global.ar-SA.resx
-Portal.Models ( hold all classes and Entity framework DbContext code first)
  - Resources
      - Global.en-GB.resx
      - Global.ar-SA.resx
-Portal.Services ( used for accessing different internal web services)
```

client requested to make the application multilingual to support different languages

so I have added the resources  files to the `Portal.UI` and converted the views titles and buttons to use these resources files
Also, I added the resources  files to the `Portal.Models` project and used the `[Display(Name="Name",typeof(Resources.Global)]` for each used property

now how can I tell `Project.Models` which resource file to use?

I mean if i changed the culture to ar-SA for example in the `Portal.UI` , it will reflected also to the `Portal.Models` automatically or I have to write code to achieve this?

any advice would be highly appreciated

Comment: If I undesrtand it correctly it should work automatically when the culture will change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource files selected according to **UICulture** (and not Culture). Assuming that Portal.Models project is a part of your deployment and is added as reference to your Portal.UI the only thing that you should do is to set a correct UICulture in your Portal.UI.

[Useful link that shows the difference between Culture and UICulture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507582/what-is-the-difference-between-culture-and-uiculture)