# Is there a way to set an application level datetime format?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

`C# / MVC` generates `datetime` in the format **MM/DD/YYYY** but sometimes i need to put in the format `DD/MM/YYYY`. This is done through giving a custom format. But instead of writing code to make C# generate datetime as `DD/MM/YYYY` is there an application level configuration i could make such as a change in `web.config`, `app.config` or `machine.config`?

Comment: You can set the culture in the `web.config` file (but not clear what your mean by _sometimes_ - do you want it to be different for different controller methods?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke so i assume that if different date formats in different controller then manual formatting but if one format the whole application it would be culture in web.config?

Comment: @StephenMuecke if you could post how to set that appreciate it, when i set this culture does it effect all the other configurations such as currency and time zone, because it should not only the time format needs the change

Comment: Yes, if your wanted to set the server culture you can use (say) `<system.web><globalization culture="en-AU" uiCulture="en-AU" />` (Australia). If you want different formats _sometimes_, then you will have to set the culture in the controller.

Comment: @StephenMuecke but does this effect the other setting such as currency and time zone etc?

Comment: Sorry, was not clear on your last comment - are you saying that you want only the date format to change (setting the culture will also affect currency etc)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes only date needs the change and nothing else : )

Comment: In that case, you would need to set the `DateTimeFormat` property of the current culture (probably in `Global.asax`).

Comment: @StephenMuecke if you could post how to set that i could give you points : )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98046/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-phill-greggan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is set the date format application-wide, you can set the Culture in the Web.config

```
<globalization culture="en-GB" />
```

However, if you are trying to reduce repetitive code, you could change the culture of the current thread and then switch it back immediately after you are finished calling `date.ToShortDateString()`. Here is a `CultureContext` class that will change the format only inside of the using block.

```
/// <summary>
/// Allows switching the current thread to a new culture in a using block that will automatically 
/// return the culture to its previous state upon completion.
/// </summary>
public class CultureContext
    : IDisposable
{
    public CultureContext(
        CultureInfo culture,
        CultureInfo uiCulture
        )
    {
        if (culture == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("culture");
        if (uiCulture == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("uiCulture");

        this.currentThread = Thread.CurrentThread;

        // Record the current culture settings so they can be restored later.
        this.originalCulture = this.currentThread.CurrentCulture;
        this.originalUICulture = this.currentThread.CurrentUICulture;

        // Set both the culture and UI culture for this context.
        this.currentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        this.currentThread.CurrentUICulture = uiCulture;
    }

    private readonly Thread currentThread;
    private readonly CultureInfo originalCulture;
    private readonly CultureInfo originalUICulture;

    public CultureInfo OriginalCulture
    {
        get { return this.originalCulture; }
    }

    public CultureInfo OriginalUICulture
    {
        get { return this.originalUICulture; }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Restore the culture to the way it was before the constructor was called.
        this.currentThread.CurrentCulture = this.originalCulture;
        this.currentThread.CurrentUICulture = this.originalUICulture;
    }
}
```

## Usage

```
// Temporarily override the current thread's culture with the invariant culture
using (var cultureContext = new CultureContext(
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture))
{
    // All date formats here will be in the invariant culture

    using (var originalCultureContext = new CultureContext(
        cultureContext.OriginalCulture, 
        cultureContext.OriginalUICulture))
    {
        // All date formats here will be in the default culture
    }

    // All date formats here will be in the invariant culture

}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507582/what-is-the-difference-between-culture-and-uiculture) to understand the difference between Culture and UI Culture.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the culture in Web.config

```
<globalization culture="en-GB"/>
```

Comment: does this effect other settings such as Currency and time zone etc