# How is the default Culture and UICulture determined?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, culture, system.web

The [`InitializeCulture()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.initializeculture.aspx) method can be overridden and you can easily choose your own [`Page.Culture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.culture.aspx) and [`Page.UICulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.uiculture.aspx). You can also add a globalization section in the `Web.config` or set the culture in your BasePage. But how are the default values of these properties determined and set exactly? Is the UICulture taken from the browser request's  accept-header? is the Culture taken from the server?

Note that I'm not asking for the [difference between these two properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507582/what-is-the-difference-between-culture-and-uiculture), but where or when the default values are set if I don't set it anywhere in my application. So which browser-, user-, server-, ...settings outside of my application influence the value?

Comment: Do you mean: IIS Manager -> Select your web site -> Select ".NET Globalization" settings, select Culture and UI Culture.

Comment: If that's the only thing that's taken into consideration, then yes, that's what I'm looking for. But if other things like the user's browser settings are taken into account as well I would love to hear about which setting trumps which setting etc.

Comment: In your link to Page.Culture it says beneath Remarks: "You can also set the value to auto which will perform automatic detection of the browser's preferred language and set it"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UICulture` is a shortcut for `Page.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`, which is, according to [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture.aspx):

> The UI culture specifies the resources an application needs to support user input and output, and by default is the same as the operating system culture.

As for `Culture`, it is again a property of a running thread, but default here is determined in a more complicated way explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). A short summary:

1. Check DefaultThreadCurrentCulture property in the application domain
2. If we are in .Net 4.6 or later and current thread is a task called by other thread, try get culture of the caller
3. By calling the Windows GetUserDefaultLocaleName function (so OS again)